# WPF Rotate line with angle from center point

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to draw lines using WPF and c# and Facing the below problem.

Imaging I have to draw  a line with fixed length, I need to rotate this line with the given angle. suppose 45 degree.
But the condition is I should rotate this from center point.
I am attaching the image for clean understanding.

[image: descriptive image]

Can any one please help me to write a C# program.

Comment: What image/drawing API are you using to render the line? or is the line a WPF view and you're trying to rotate that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To rotate the line by a custom angle, apply a [RotateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) to it. You can set [RenderTransformOrigin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) property to `0.5 0.5` to rotate around center point.

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
        <Line.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
        </Line.RenderTransform>
    </Line>
</Grid>
```

If the angle is fixed (e.g. always the same), you can calculate coordinates of the start and end points, and draw a diagonal line without using transform:

```
<Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="200" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Answer (score 3):

here's the idea, you need to improve it, shape it to what you need

```
    private void Rotate()
    {
        while (Degrees >= 360)
            Degrees -= 360;
        while (Degrees <= -360)
            Degrees += 360;

        X1 = 0;
        Y1 = 0;
        var rad = Degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        const int radius = 100;
        var sin = Math.Sin(rad);
        var cos = Math.Cos(rad);
        var tan = Math.Tan(rad);

        Y2 = sin * radius;
        X2 = cos * radius;

    }
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Content="Rotation" />
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Degrees}" Width="50" Margin="5,5,0,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="°" />
        <Button Content="Rotate" Margin="5" Command="{Binding RotateCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid    Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Line Stroke="Red" X1="{Binding X1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" Y2="{Binding Y2}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```